# share printer on a public wifi

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu, printing, vpn

I work for an association hosted by computing society. They only allow us tu use a public wifi named society_public for internet connexion. Our old printer has not wifi connexion and I want to share it for all the association members. I have thinked to use a litle pc with lubuntu to create a printer server but I think I can't because I need to have a complete private network on server and on client. Do you know how I can proceed? Maybe a VPN connexion could be a solution? Do you know an appropriate tutorial for that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "public wifi"? Is it a WiFi without any encryption? (Like "Open") or does it just show the WiFi ID in public, but you still have to enter a password or key to connect to the WiFi? Also: what is your goal with the printer - who should be allowed to print? From where? (Over the internet, or just from within the same WiFi?)

Comment: Oh and one more question: what operating system will the users of the printer run?

Comment: It is an encrypt wifi and all the member of the association have the same password for internet connexion. The wifi ID terminates with "public". I would like to share the printer to all association members who use just from within the same WiFi? The users use mainly windows as operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your printer does neither have ethernet nor Wifi itself, I would recommend that you look for a dedicated printserver device. Those should be around 70€, for that price you will hardly get a small computer that does the same - if you don't have one in spare that won't be used otherwise.

Still these days you also have to consider the energy cost, and most "small computers" have a higher power consumption than those dedicated devices.

Your network seems to be sufficient secure, but you want to use a printserver that allows for access control - this way you can limit printer access to users that are allowed to do so.

Maybe also your Wifi router for the "..._public" Wifi has a free USB port where you can connect your printer to? Or you have some spare Wifi router with a USB port that you can flash with an alternative OS (like OpenWRT) to connect as a Wifi client but also provides a printserver.

UPDATE:
You described in your comments that the WiFi you use has "Client Device Isolation" activated. Unfortunately it means, you will have to put your print server at least virtually "outside" the WiFI LAN - and your idea with the VPN will be necessary. But the VPN provider will have to be outside the WiFi.

An Alternative would be a remote printing service that some printer manufacturers offer (I know of HP Print Anywhere, Epson Remote Print and Canon Cloud, but there might be more. Keywords for a search are "remote printing".)
As far as I know only printers with a built in network interface offer this remote printing, and you cannot use it with an external "print server". (Unfortunately Google Cloud Print ran out of service early 2021, that would have been a nice solution for you.)

So you will have to have some server instance (VPN or print server) running outside of your WiFi where both side connect to: the printer (or the print server where the printer is connected to) and the client(s).

Comment: I don't have acess to wifi router so I can't plug anything on it. The only thing I can plug is USB on a small pc like a raspberry. It seems to me that  if I try to use whatever kind of printer server it won't work because the wifi type is public. I won't be able to ping between the small pc and an other pc which wants to print. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you ping any other PC on the same WiFi if you know its IP address?

Comment: No I can't. So I was thinking it is because  the wifi type is public.